# Wrong service reference is being generated on update

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

I am having this wierd issue while trying to update my service reference. I have a WCF service which takes some parameters, and one of them is a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I created my project, added the service reference, everything is working fine. I configured the collection type and dictionary type properly, and its fine too. But when I add a new method on my service, or change signature of one of my methods I need to update my service reference naturally. But when I do that, all types are breaking, `Guid`s are turning into `string`s, `XElement`s turns into `XmlElement`, and `Dictionary<string, string>` wierdly turns into `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[]` this. When I create a new project and add same service reference its fine again. I'm lost, help me out maybe with some documents about service references.

What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I try produce your situation in different ways, but all of them work fine. when configure your service please uncheck Reuse types in referenced assemblies and try update service reference, may it works.

Comment: Yes actually I tried that and it worked, and before I answer my own question, you've come up with that comment. If you put it as answer I would accept it, otherwise I will make my own answer. But there is still an issue bugging my head, which is I am using this service from some other projects too, and in them even if the `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` is checked, reference works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when configure your service please uncheck Reuse types in referenced assemblies and try update service reference.